# String Format an integer to look like a social security number

Tags: java, string-formatting

After the users input of a social security number I would like to take the integer that is entered and display is as a social security number. So that XXXXXXXXX becomes XXX-XX-XXXX.

```
 public String getSSNumber()
        {      
            String convert;
            convert = String.valueOf(ssNumber);
            return convert;
        }

 public String toString()
        {
           return (" SSN: " + String.format("%03d-%02d-%04d", ssNumber);
        }
```

This is the code I tried, and I just can't seem to get it to work. Forgive the gross code I'm a new student to java.

Comment: I dont work a lot with String.format, but i think its because each %d expects a variable. you provide only one, so it will not work as expected.

Comment: you could instead try to load the string into a string builder and insert at the correct indexes the "-"

Comment: please do research before asking, at the very least study the javadoc of each method you are using ..

Comment: Generally, you shouldn't use integers to represent things like social security number

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`String.format` is the wrong tool for the job. It cannot do what you want. Java sees 3 `%d` values and thus wants you to pass 3 numbers to it.

You need to do the work of chopping the number into its parts on your own. You can either use integer wrangling for it, or string wrangling.

### int wrangling

.. though you may want to use `long`.

Given `123456789`, you need to obtain:

- `123`
- `45`
- `6789`

To that, you can divide by the relevant number: `123456789 / 1000000` is `123`.

For `45`, you need to combine modulo and division. First, you want to lop off the 123, which requires modulo, then lop off the 6789 which requires division. `123456789 % 1000000` is `3456789`. Divide that by `10000` and you get `45`. Alternatively, keep 'updating' the number: Once you get 123 out subtract that times 1000000.

```
long ssn = 123_45_6789L;
int p1 = ssn / 1_00_0000;
int p2 = (ssn % 1_00_0000) / 1_0000;
int p3 = ssn % 1_0000;
return String.format("%03d-%02d-%04d", p1, p2, p3);
```

### String wrangling

(EDIT: Replaced with @OleV.V.'s far more elegant take).

First turn your number into a string then inject the dashes:

```
long ssn = 123456789L;
String a = String.format("%09d", ssn)
  .replaceFirst("(\\d{3})(\\d{2})(\\d{4})", "$1-$2-$3");
```

either one works fine - but the second (string wrangling) example strikes me as more readable.